# iOS: _main referenced from _main$non_lazy_ptr

Tags: iphone, linker, reference, program-entry-point

I am trying to create an executable using the following linker command:

```
/path/to/ld64/i686-apple-darwin9-ld64 -ObjC -dead_strip -L/ -o ../someoutput -exported_symbol _main -Z -F/full/path/to/frameworks -lgcc -lgcc_s.1 -arch arm -lstdc++.6 -lcrt1.o -lSystem.B -lz -lobjc -framework CoreFoundation -framework UIKit -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreGraphics -framework Foundation -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenGLES -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework AVFoundation -framework Security
```

However, I get some warnings like those given below and after that I am getting a fatal error which makes no sense to me:

```
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$hide$os2.1$_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURL in dylib /full/path/to/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$hide$os2.1$_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSURL in dylib /full/path/to/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$hide$os2.2$_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURL in dylib /full/path/to/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$add$os2.2$_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURL in dylib /full/path/to/Foundation.framework/Foundation
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$add$os2.2$_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSURL in dylib /full/path/to/Foundation.framework/Foundation
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$add$os3.0$_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURL in dylib /full/path/to/Foundation.framework/Foundation
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$add$os3.0$_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSURL in dylib /full/path/to/Foundation.framework/Foundation
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$add$os3.1$_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURL in dylib /full/path/to/Foundation.framework/Foundation

Undefined symbols:
  "_main", referenced from:
       _main$non_lazy_ptr in crt1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

What does this mean? How can I resolve this?

Comment: You can see in the linker symbols the different versions of iOS (2.1, 2.2, 3.0, 3.1 ...). My guess is that when XCode calls the linker, it passes a define or flag indicating the target version, and then the linker will use that in a bunch of conditional statements to omit all other versions of certain symbols. Check `man ld` on your Mac.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?I'm getting the same thing, while trying to compile an Objective-C app that is using the Apple APIs. I'm getting it to compile and it seems to work for me though, the warnings are just annoying. It seems like it would just be some gcc flag that needs to be set or something....

Comment: Nope :(. Have resigned myself to seeing them every time I build.